# Show the list of questions in incremental order in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I do have the list of questions, which I want to display in sequential manner. The current code displays the question in random order. Would you please assist me to show all the questions in sequential manner? Here is the code:

```
function questionconstructor(question, answers, correctanswer){
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = answers;
    this.correctanswer = correctanswer;
}
var q1 = new questionconstructor('what do you want to do?', ['Job','WFH', 'Business'], 2);
var q2 = new questionconstructor('Where do you want to go?', ['USA', 'UK', 'JAP'], 1);
var q3 = new questionconstructor('Which car do you use?', ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Honda'], 0);
var questions = [q1, q2, q3];

questionconstructor.prototype.displayquestion = function(){
    console.log(this.question);
    for (var i=0; i < this.answers.length; i++){
        console.log(i + ':' + this.answers[i]);
    }
}
questionconstructor.prototype.checkanswer = function(ans){
    if(ans === this.correctanswer){
        console.log("Correct Answer!")
    }else{
        console.log("Try Again!")
    }
}
function displaynextque(){
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
console.log(rand);
questions[rand].displayquestion();
    var answerofperson = prompt("please select your answer!")
    if (answerofperson !== 'exit'){
        questions[rand].checkanswer(parseInt(answerofperson));
        displaynextque();
    }
}
displaynextque();
```

Thank you.

Comment: you just need to keep  count of the last displayed question index, show the next one and increment the count, instead of generating a random number every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a global `index` variable and increment it while smaller than the length.

```js
function questionconstructor(question, answers, correctanswer) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = answers;
    this.correctanswer = correctanswer;
}

questionconstructor.prototype.displayquestion = function () {
    console.log(this.question);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.answers.length; i++) {
        console.log(i + ':' + this.answers[i]);
    }
}
questionconstructor.prototype.checkanswer = function (ans) {
    if (ans === this.correctanswer) {
        console.log("Correct Answer!")
    } else {
        console.log("Try Again!")
    }
}

function displaynextque() {
    questions[index].displayquestion();
    var answerofperson = prompt(questions[index].question + ' (' + questions[index].answers.map(function (a, i) { return [i, a].join(': '); }).join(', ') + '):')
    if (answerofperson !== 'exit') {
        questions[index].checkanswer(parseInt(answerofperson));
        index++;
        if (index < questions.length) {
            displaynextque();
        }
    }
}

var q1 = new questionconstructor('what do you want to do?', ['Job', 'WFH', 'Business'], 2),
    q2 = new questionconstructor('Where do you want to go?', ['USA', 'UK', 'JAP'], 1),
    q3 = new questionconstructor('Which car do you use?', ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Honda'], 0),
    questions = [q1, q2, q3],
    index = 0;

displaynextque();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last function to this:

```
function displaynextque(n){
var count = n ? n : 0;

questions[count].displayquestion();
var answerofperson = prompt("please select your answer!")
if (answerofperson !== 'exit'){
questions[count].checkanswer(parseInt(answerofperson));
if(count < questions.length - 1) {  
displaynextque(count+1);
}
}
}
displaynextque();
```